# .addClass to only the bullet being clicked on in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I have a short unordered list with two bullets.

I added some Javascript, so that when I bullet is clicked on, it adds a class to it.

The problem is, it adds the class to all existing li's, not just the one I clicked on.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4sa8T/

Javascript:

```
$("#items li a").click(function(){

$("#items li").addClass("newClass");

});
```

html:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="items">
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bye</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use this. It creates situational scope, your current code is a blanket statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#items li a").click(function(){
    $("#items li").addClass("newClass");
});
```

should be

```
$("#items li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("newClass");
});
```

`$(this).parent()` would refer to the specific `li` element, and `$('#items li')` refers to **all** `li`s under `#items`

Comment: yep, and remove "" around this

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you is using:

```
$(this).toggleClass('newClass');
```

dollar **this** indicates using the specific clicked element...

**toggleClass** is an easy way to remove the added class by clicking the element again.

here is a demo [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hJF9m/)